# Does javadoc scans all the classes everytime Generate JavaDoc command is given?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I am using `IntelliJ` and I generate `JavaDoc` like below.

[image: Generate JavaDoc]
[image: Scope]

Does this generate html for all the classes, all the time this is done? Unlike how compiler compiles only the changed/modified files and refuses to compile if all the files are up to date? I am asking this because it takes lot of time to complete and the log contains lot of classes instead of only the edited one.

When I select the `File` option (assuming, the update will happen to only that file's html), the index.html only now contains that particular file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaDoc does not support Incremental Builds as it seems. It generates a new document every time.

From the JavaDoc FAQ:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#incrementalbuild

> A9.  Can I incrementally build a document from different runs of Javadoc?
>
> Basically no, but there is a link feature that may provide what you need. First of all,  Javadoc generates one and only one document each time you run it. It cannot modify or  directly incorporate results from previous runs of Javadoc.